# PHP - Only the path is output instead of the page

Tags: php, function, dynamic

I have a small problem with my function, which is supposed to do nothing but output the web page more dynamically via domain.com/index.php?page=start.

My problem is that only the path is displayed, but not the content of the start.html.

My index.php:

```
<?php
require_once './ext/config.php';
require_once './ext/functions.php';

$page = isset($_GET["page"]) ? $_GET["page"] : "default";
$pc   = "$website_pages/$page" .".html";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title><?php echo $website_title; ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
 
       <?php echo $pc; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

My function.php:

```
<?php

function getPage($pagename) {
    global  $website_pages;
    $path = "$website_pages/$pagename";
    
    if (file_exists($path)) {
        return openPage($path);
    } else {
        echo "Error";
        return openPage("$website_pages/includes/default.html");
    }
}


function openPage($pageurl) {
    $fh = fopen($pageurl, "r");
    $fc = fread($fh, filesize($pageurl));
    
    fclose($fh);
    
    return $fc;
}

?>
```

My config.php:

```
<?php
$website_title =    "Title";
$website_charset =  "UTF-8";
$website_pages =    "includes";
?>
```

Output in browser:
includes/start.html

Maybe you can help me?

regards

Comment: Functions need calling otherwise they are just pretty bits of code

Comment: You are outputting the path variable and nothing else right here: `<?php echo $pc; ?>`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply.
Sorry to ask, but could you make an example of what you mean?

Comment: To understand your code, please also share the content of  the includes/default.html
Depending on what is inside there you can echo that and not the path-variable.